# How to read an online file as variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

i found this code that can read text files from online

```
fetch("link.txt")
.then(r => r.text())
.then(t => console.log(t));
```

but how do i make it return the text files instead of writing it to the console. I'm not so good at using the fetch function and i've tried everything i could think of but it just won't work

Comment: What do you mean "return"?

Comment: @evolutionxbox something like ```let a = fetch(....)``` then if i call **console.log(a)** the text file will be logged into the console

Comment: You're looking async/await, or do everything in the "then" callbacks.